# What is e(fx)clipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am going to learn about JavaFX and something called e(fx)clipse, seems to be a tool which seems to be an important tool for development in JavaFX environment. I have already encountered issues with access restrictions, which is said to be something that e(fx)clipse can handle. However, I am not really sure what else the plugin does. From [the eclipse homepage](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) It seems there is a lot of support for JavaFX, including ha Scene Builder, which seems to be quite useful. However, when e(fx)clipse is mentioned it sounds like a whole new IDE. **So what is e(fx)clipse and do I need to do a full reinstall of Eclipse to be able to use all features?**

Comment: It is Eclipse with a lot of plugins for JavaFX, see [here](https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Eclipse website](http://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/january/article3.php) :

> **e(fx)clipse - JavaFX tooling and runtime**
>
> **What is e(fx)clipse**
>
> **Tooling**
>
> e(fx)clipse is an Eclipse.org project that provides JavaFX
>   capabilities for the Eclipse IDE, so that people can easily develop
>   JavaFX applications inside their favorite IDE.
>
> To make the development process as smooth as possible, it provides the
>   following:
>
> - automatic detection of JavaFX inside JDK7 and JDK8 specialized
> - CSS-Editor who knows all custom JavaFX’ attributes specialized
> - FXML-Editor on top of WST-XML including a live preview wizards to
> - bootstrap standard JavaFX projects and OSGi enabled JavaFX projects
>
> **Runtime**
>
> Additionally, e(fx)clipse also provides runtime components to develop
>   OSGi enabled JavaFX applications, including otherwise missing features
>   when using JavaFX in an OSGi environment.
>
> Besides providing single components to develop pure OSGi applications,
>   it also provides a complete framework implementation on top of the
>   core Eclipse 4 technologies (modelled application and DI container),
>   allowing people to develop RCP applications with any level of
>   complexity.

Comment: So basically I can just go to "Help => install new software" and add the address to the download page. Then I am ready to go? No more stuff needed. FYI, I run on Eclipse Mars.

Comment: Can you paste the link of the download page for e(fx)clipse. I can't seem to find it.